# carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange on iCarousel only being called when I swipe

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, icarousel

I'm using iCarousel in my Swift+Sprite Kit game, where the user has unlocked and locked items.

The locked items would display some info like current user coins, and some text that says "UNLOCK THIS FOR: X amount of coins", if the carousel item isn't locked, it won't display any of that information, just a button that says "Select".

Now, I got that working, but it will only work when i start swiping the items and not the first time the carousel shows up.

To make that work, I do it inside carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange() method. And that obviously changes when I swipe.

How can I set the current carousel index at start so then I can force to show or not show the information depending if the item is locked or unlocked and not only when I start swiping?

To add more information about this, imagine that the user selected the item at index 4, i save that index locally. So if the user closes and opens the game, the carousel should begin at 4 not 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should set it up in `viewForItemAtIndex`, not the delegate method you are using

Comment: which one??? this func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView { ? but that isn't only called when you create the carousel and never called again?

Comment: No, that method is called each time a view needs to be displayed. It works like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`; when views scroll of screen they are discarded and retrieved from this method when they come back onto the screen. If there is a change to the underlying data that affects a view you can call `reloadItemAtIndex` and then the carousel view will call `viewForItemAtIndex` to get the updated view.

Comment: I checked yesterday if i had a method called viewForItemAtIndex and i couldn't find it in iCarousel. Is it possible?

Comment: The thing is, if the user selected the item at index 4. I save that index locally. If the user closes the game and opens it again, the carousel should start at index 4 now, not 0. That's what i would like to do.

Comment: When i said `viewForItemAtIndex` I was just saving typing. The full name is the method you said, `viewForItemAtIndex: reusingView:`.  To start from item 4, you would call `scrollToItemAtIndex:animated:` probably somewhere like `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Thanks! i will give that a try! :)

Comment: You were totally right! thanks a lot! put it as an answer and i will mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up your carousel views in `viewForItemAtIndex: reusingView:`.  The view returned by this method should represent the current state of that carousel item; so locked or "Select" as appropriate.

If the state of an item changes then you can call `reloadItemAtIndex:` to have iCarousel request an updated view for that item by calling `viewForItemAtIndex: reusingView:`.

You can scroll the carousel to a particular item by calling `scrollToItemAtIndex:animated:`